# Error during calling resource in IBM Mobilefirst 8.0.0 by HTTPRequest with accesstoken

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In some cases, when we obtain the access token after login by security check and use it to request the resource by HTTP request, we faced that error:

```
bm.mfp.server.persistency.internal.PersistentStorageJdbcImpl E FWLSE3006E: Couldnt start transaction :'{0}'.
p.server.security.internal.context.ClientSecurityContextImpl W FWLSE4229W: Re-read of initialized client context, the changes may be lost.
```

I don't know if there is any problem when we don't use the WL lib but HTTP request with access token?

Thanks

Comment: What is the MFP8 build level you are at ?Can you also update if this is happening with Devkit / production ? If production, Please also update the Database in use and the version

Comment: Also paste the complete stack which would have followed this error to understand clearly the flow leading to this.

Comment: Is your resource protected by Multiple Security Checks ? Can you check the behavior by explicitly passing the scope for which token is needed ?